# Why ist the Resttemplate with Response Type String slow

Tags: java, spring, performance, rest

I've compared the following code to the performance:

```
restTemplate.exchange(
                url.toLowerCase().startsWith("http") ? url : getBasePath() + url,
                httpMethod,
                httpEntity,
                new ParameterizedTypeReference<List<T>>() {}
        ).getBody()
```

100 Requests with ExecutorService takes 0.7 sec.
100 Requests without ExecutorService takes 5 sec.

```
restTemplate.exchange(
                url.toLowerCase().startsWith("http") ? url : getBasePath() + url,
                httpMethod,
                httpEntity,
                String.class
        ).getBody();
```

The same 100 Requests with ExecutorService takes 4 sec.
The same 100 Requests without ExecutorService takes 10 sec.

Comment: How can you be sure the difference is spent inside your core, and not on the server side ? How can the same call return either a List or a String (this looks like you're not calling the same URL on the two samples,  would defeat any comparison) ?

Comment: Becourse each Test delivers the same result.
The Webservice returns a Json. If i specify String as Response Type the Method returns the Json String. If i specify the Response Type as ParameterizedTypeReference<List<T>>() {} i get a List of Linked Hash Maps.

Comment: By saying `without ExecutorService` you mean single-threaded? I.e. you do 100 requests in a loop in the `without ExecutorService` case?

Comment: Yes, i mean single-threaded.